# API to get html formatted content in monaco-editor?

Tags: clipboard, monaco-editor

I would like to programatically obtain the formatted text from a monaco-editor instance.

When i say formatted text i mean syntax highlighting - what I get when I copy a text from monaco and paste it into outlook (or any other application that supports pasting html content).

My goal is to put it on the clipboard together with some other text (that monaco-editor does not have access to).

How can i achieve that?

Comment: When you say "formatted" you mean just the whitespace or do you want the colours and syntax highlighting also?

Comment: @rcjsuen - I mean the colours and syntax highlighting also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/866

The answer would be

```
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "function hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}",
    language: "javascript"
});

setTimeout(function() {
    const html = editor.viewModel.getHTMLToCopy([editor.getModel().getFullModelRange()], false);
    console.log(html);
}, 2000);
```